# What happens to Debian Unstable packages before getting into Ubuntu?

Tags: package-management, 20.04

Ubuntu packages in regular releases (the ones that get updated every six months) come from Debian Unstable.

Do Debian Unstable packages get patched/fixed/tested before making their way into Ubuntu regular release?

Is the following picture still relevant?

[image: package graph]

The Debian node in the picture is Debian unstable?

Comment: Please be aware this won't apply for all packages. I believe @user535733's answer applies mostly to 'main' or Ubuntu packages (plus many others too!), however the 'universe' packages I'm involved with, the source is from upstream at GitHub, and Ubuntu is ahead of Debian most of the time. For other flavors & packages the same Ubuntu people also work by getting it into Debian (packaging for both) to avoid doing things twice, but Debian & Ubuntu have freezes at different so any general rule won't apply across all Ubuntu repositories.  *writing as Ubuntu flavor & Debian sid user too*

Answer (score 2):

Debian Unstable packages are tested and patched...by Debian volunteers...before going into Unstable.

Ubuntu's policy is to minimize the difference with stock Debian in most circumstances. Some packages carry additional patches, but not many.

Packages are tested for just under 6 months, with lots of bugfixes and patches. (Those bug reports and patches are also forwarded to Debian and to Upstream).

In fact, Ubuntu is just wrapping up one of those cycles now. 20.10 will be released in a couple weeks, after over 5 months of testing and bugfixing.